# Why do I get a DiscordAPIError when trying to edit a user as they leave a voice channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Let me preface this by saying that this is my first attempt at coding a Discord bot. Also, I have been pounding my head into this for the past couple of days, so my brain feels like mush. That being said, I apologize if the answer to this seems obvious to others.

To explain what I'm doing here, my bot is used with a particular game where there are periods of time that we don't want people to be able to hear each other talking (or involuntarily reacting to what is happening in the game). The person running the game uses commands, which will mute or unmute everyone in the voice channel. The bot works perfectly in that respect. It has been tested, many times over, by multiple people.

I wanted to add a contingency, however, because we don't want someone who leaves the game prematurely to end up server-muted indefinitely (until an admin can do something about it). My answer to this was to have a specific role which is assigned when they are muted and removed when they are unmuted. Then, the bot should check for that role when the person leaves the voice channel and, if they have it, makes sure the role is removed and the person is unmuted. (This ensures that if they are server-muted for a reason OTHER than this bot, they can't use the bot functionality to get around that.)

So here is what I've written (and rewritten a number of times, trying to get it to work):

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    let oldServer = oldState.guild;
    let oldChannel = oldState.channel;
    let oldMember = oldState.member;
    // If user leaves a voice channel (ignores voiceStateUpdate caused by muting/unmuting in other functions).
    if (oldChannel && oldChannel !== newState.channel) {
        console.log(`${oldMember.user.tag} left channel ${oldChannel.name} (${oldServer.name}).`);
        // Check if they have the "Hushed" role.
        if (oldMember.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Hushed')) {
            // Remove the "Hushed" role, if the user has it.
            let role = oldServer.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Hushed');
            oldMember.roles.remove(role).catch(console.error);
            console.log(`- "Hushed" role removed from ${oldMember.user.tag}.`);
            // Unmute this member.
            oldMember.voice.setMute(false);
            console.log(`- User ${oldMember.user.tag} unmuted.`);
        }
    }
})
```

It recognizes when someone leaves a voice channel and knows whether they have the role, because my console.log messages print to the console window, but that seems to be where the functionality stops. It doesn't remove the role or unmute the user. Here is my console.log (I've masked any information I consider private, for obvious reasons):

```
MY_DISCORD_TAG left channel Testing (MY_DISCORD_SERVER).
- "Hushed" role removed from MY_DISCORD_TAG.
- User MY_DISCORD_TAG unmuted.
(node:17092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Target user is not connected to voice.
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\MY_NAME\Discord\Hush\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:17092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17092) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm not new to programming or debugging my own code, and can usually figure these things out on my own (either through reading the documentation or searching on Google). After struggling with this for a couple of days, though, I'm having no luck. So I decided to try and reach out to the community. I would appreciate any assistance with getting to the bottom of what is causing this to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Discord documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#modify-guild-member) says that trying to set the muteness/deafness of a user when they are not in a voice channel will throw an error, so you can't unmute a user once they have left a channel. Instead, you could unmute the user if they join a channel (after not being in a channel) with the ‘Hushed’ role:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate',(oldState, newState) => {
    let oldServer = oldState.guild;
    let oldChannel = oldState.channel;
    let oldMember = oldState.member;
    let newChannel = newState.channel;

    // If the user changed voice channels or the user joined a channel (after not being in one)
    if (oldChannel && newChannel && oldChannel !== newChannel || !oldChannel) {
        // Check if they have the "Hushed" role.
        if (oldMember.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Hushed')) {
            // Remove the "Hushed" role, if the user has it.
            let role = oldServer.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Hushed');
            oldMember.roles.remove(role)
                .then(() => {
                    // This will be logged after the role has been successfully removed.
                    // As removing roles is asynchronous, your code would have logged this
                    // regardless of whether the role was actually removed.
                    console.log(`- "Hushed" role removed from ${oldMember.user.tag}.`);
                    // Unmute this member.
                    return oldMember.voice.setMute(false);
                })
                .then(() => console.log(`- User ${oldMember.user.tag} unmuted.`))
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

With ES2017's `async`/`await`:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
    let oldServer = oldState.guild;
    let oldChannel = oldState.channel;
    let oldMember = oldState.member;
    let newChannel = newState.channel;

    // If the user changed voice channels or the user joined a channel (after not being in one)
    if (oldChannel && newChannel && oldChannel !== newChannel || !oldChannel) {
        // Check if they have the "Hushed" role.
        if (oldMember.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Hushed')) {
            // Remove the "Hushed" role, if the user has it.
            let role = oldServer.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Hushed');
            try {
                await oldMember.roles.remove(role);
                console.log(`- "Hushed" role removed from ${oldMember.user.tag}.`);
                // Unmute this member.
                await oldMember.voice.setMute(false);
                console.log(`- User ${oldMember.user.tag} unmuted.`);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. I did say my brain was mush! Thank you so much for helping, this was absolutely what the issue was.